# What's the difference between mounting a drive with rw and chmod +rw?

Tags: linux, mount, chmod

I know that mounting a drive with "rw" would mount the file system as read/write, but what does that even mean? What's the difference between setting read and write via `chmod`?

Comment: a read-write mount is the default. A read-only mount will prevent all writes to all files, for all users, regardless of permissions or being root etc. Plus the error message is different.

Comment: Try mounting a partition read-only then try editing a file or changing its permissions. Perhaps using a physical CD/DVD would be a good test.

Comment: You may not be old enough to remember floppy disks, but all formats of floppy had a physical method of write-protecting the _entire media_. (Either by means of a switch built into the outer casing, or a notch punched at a certain location on its edge.) Mounting a filesystem read-only is like inserting a write-protected floppy. IFF the filesystem _isn't_ write-protected (is mounted `rw`), then the filesystem's ownership and permission semantics can be used to administratively permit/deny certain users' processes write access to individual files/directories.

Answer (score 11):

`chmod` sets the permission for individual files, based on its owner and group. `mount` options apply to the entire filesystem, *including its metadata*.

For instance, a file's access time is updated every time it is read, even if no one has permissions to write to it.  If the filesystem is mounted `ro`, then the access time won't be updated.

Comment: Thank you that made it much clearer. So just let me add another question. Is ls -l actually showing any information if a drive is mounted for example read only? Or does it just represent the permissions set via umask/chmod?

Comment: `ls -l` shows you the permissions for each node (file or directory), its ownership (user and group) and (usually) the node's last modification time. The permissions shown are those of the _node_, regardless of how the filesystem was mounted (i.e. you might see nodes with `write` permissions on `ro` filesystems). Use `mount` with no arguments to see how the filesystem was mounted.

Answer (score 7):

`mount` options apply to the entire file system, but also are specific to the state of it being mounted. You can unmount and remount a file system with different options. A read-write file system can be unmounted and the physical drive moved out into a separate machine, which then mounts it read-only. When mounted read-only, all write operations will fail regardless of file permissions.

`chmod` modifies the metadata within the filesystem to alter the permissions of a specific file, such that a particular file can be made read-only or read-write for owner, group, or others.

The effective permissions at runtime would be the combination of the most restrictive permissions. For example, a file that is readable and writable by its owner cannot be modified if the file system is mounted read-only. Likewise, a file with read-only permissions cannot be modified, even when its file system is mounted read-write.

Comment: That was a really helpful example ty

Answer (score 5):

Mount options apply just for the time the filesystem is mounted, and for that particular mount. You could mount it somewhere else with different options at the same time (e.g. `rw` in one folder, and `ro` somewhere else).

`chmod` *modifies* the files' permission bits **persistently**, i.e. on-disk. It will affect every mount of the filesystem. For that reason you can only do that on a filesystem mounted `rw`.